# Apply function to a whole dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, function

I downloaded data from an api and it got pretty messy. I have this dataframe and I am trying to apply a function to get data after ":". The catch is that there are some cells with more than one ":". I tried the following.

```
matrix = [('points:31','points:25'),
          ('name:Deportes wigan','name:Deportes loco'),
          ('team:id:1059','team:id:1057'),
          ('league:id:1000','league:id:1000')
         ]
```

Create a Dataframe object

```
df= pd.DataFrame(matrix, columns = list('ab'))
df
```

I want the following df :

```
31, 25
Deportes wigan,Deportes loco
1059, 1057
1000 , 1000
```

I tried

```
new_df = ejemplo.apply(lambda x : x.split(":")[-1])
new_df
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DataFrame.applymap`

```py
new_df = ejemplo.applymap(lambda x : x.split(":")[-1])
```

```
print(new_df)

                a              b
0              31             25
1  Deportes wigan  Deportes loco
2            1059           1057
3            1000           1000
```

Or with `Series.str.split`

```py
new_df = ejemplo.apply(lambda col: col.str.split(":").str[-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can post-process the data with [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
df = (pd.DataFrame(matrix, columns = list('ab'))
        .apply(lambda s: s.str.extract('(?<=:)([^:]*$)', expand=False))
     )
```

output:

```
                a              b
0              31             25
1  Deportes wigan  Deportes loco
2            1059           1057
3            1000           1000
```